# How to prove that $\arctan({y \over x})$ does not conform to $yZ_x=xZ_y$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, proof-verification, chain-rule

> Prove that $\arctan({y \over x})$ does not conform to $yZ_x=xZ_y$ in the first quarter namely $D=\{(x,y)|x>0,y>0 \}$.

I guess this can be proved straightforwardly from the calculation:
$$
Z_x={dz \over dx}=-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\\
Z_y={dz \over dy}=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}
$$
Therefore:
$$
yZ_x=xZ_y \Leftrightarrow y\cdot -\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}=x\cdot \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}
$$

Which is a contradiction. What puzzles me why does the exercise say "in the first quarter"? As far as I see this inequality will hold in ***any*** quarter.

Comment: The function isn't defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, so they just chose a region of it where $Z$ is defined.

Comment: @florence Nice! so they could've also said to prove it the third quarter right?

Comment: Yes, they could have